# Why tensorflow1.1 gets slower and slower when training? Is it memory leak or queue starvation?

Tags: memory-leaks, tensorflow

I trained a ESPCN in tensorflow1.1, the costed time per patch increase nearly linearly when training. The first 100 epoch takes only 4-5 seconds, but the 70th epoch takes about half a minute. See the training result below:

[image]
[image]

I've searched the same question on Google and Stack-overflow, and tried the solutions below, but seemed no work:
1.add `tf.reset_default_graph()` after every `sess.run()`;
2.add `time.sleep(5)` to prevent queue starvation;

I know the general idea, that is to reduce the operations in Session(). But how? Anyone have the solution?

Here's part of my code:

```
L3, var_w_list, var_b_list = model_train(IN, FLAGS)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(OUT - L3), reduction_indices=0))

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(FLAGS.base_lr, global_step * FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.decay_step, 0.96, staircase=True)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost, global_step = global_step, var_list = var_w_list + var_b_list)
# optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(cost, var_list = var_w_list + var_b_list)

cnt = 0

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
    print('\n\n\n =========== All initialization finished, now training begins ===========\n\n\n')
    t_start = time.time()
    t1 = t_start

    for i in range(1, FLAGS.max_Epoch + 1):

        LR_batch, HR_batch = batch.__next__()
        global_step += 1
        [_, cost1] = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {IN: LR_batch, OUT: HR_batch})
        # tf.reset_default_graph()

        if i % 100 == 0 or i == 1:
            print_step = i
            print_loss = cost1 / FLAGS.batch_size

            test_LR_batch, test_HR_batch = test_batch.__next__()
            test_SR_batch = test_HR_batch.copy()
            test_SR_batch[:,:,:,0:3] = sess.run(L3, feed_dict = {IN: test_LR_batch[:,:,:,0:3]})
            # tf.reset_default_graph()
            psnr_tmp = 0.0
            ssim_tmp = 0.0

            for k in range(test_SR_batch.shape[0]):
                com1 = test_SR_batch[k, :, :, 0]
                com2 = test_HR_batch[k, :, :, 0]
                psnr_tmp += get_psnr(com1, com2, FLAGS.HR_size, FLAGS.HR_size)
                ssim_tmp += get_ssim(com1, com2, FLAGS.HR_size, FLAGS.HR_size)

            psnr[cnt] = psnr_tmp / test_SR_batch.shape[0]
            ssim[cnt] = ssim_tmp / test_SR_batch.shape[0]
            ep[cnt] = print_step
            t2 = time.time()
            print_time = t2 - t1
            t1 = t2

            print(("[Epoch] : {0:d} [Current cost] : {1:5.8f} \t [Validation PSNR] : {2:5.8f} \t [Duration time] : {3:10.8f} s \n").format(print_step, print_loss, psnr[cnt], print_time))
            # tf.reset_default_graph()

            cnt += 1

        if i % 1000 == 0:

            L3_test = model_test(IN_TEST, var_w_list, var_b_list, FLAGS)

            output_img = single_HR.copy()
            output_img[:,:,:,0:3] = sess.run(L3_test, feed_dict = {IN_TEST:single_LR[:,:,:,0:3]})
            tf.reset_default_graph()
            subname = FLAGS.img_save_dir + '/' + str(i) + ".jpg" 
            img_gen(output_img[0,:,:,:], subname)

            print(('================= Saving model to {}/model.ckpt ================= \n').format(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir))

            time.sleep(5)

            # saver.save(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint_dir + '/model.ckpt', print_step)

t_tmp = time.time() - t_start
```

My configuration is: windows10 + tf1.1 + python3.5 + cuda8.0 + cudnn5.1

================================================================

Besides, I used pixel-shuffle(PS) layer instead of deconvolution in the last layer. I copied the PS code from others, which is shown below:

```
def _phase_shift(I, r):
    bsize, a, b, c = I.get_shape().as_list()
    bsize = tf.shape(I)[0] # Handling Dimension(None) type for undefined batch dim
    X = tf.reshape(I, (bsize, a, b, r, r))
    X = tf.transpose(X, (0, 1, 2, 4, 3))  # bsize, a, b, 1, 1
    X = tf.split(X, a, 1)  # a, [bsize, b, r, r]
    X = tf.concat([tf.squeeze(x, axis=1) for x in X], 2)  # bsize, b, a*r, r
    X = tf.split(X, b, 1)  # b, [bsize, a*r, r]
    X = tf.concat([tf.squeeze(x, axis=1) for x in X], 2)  # bsize, a*r, b*r
    return tf.reshape(X, (bsize, a*r, b*r, 1))

def PS(X, r, color=False):
    if color:
        Xc = tf.split(X, 3, 3)
        X = tf.concat([_phase_shift(x, r) for x in Xc], 3)
    else:
        X = _phase_shift(X, r)
    return X
```

Which `X` is the 4-dimensional image tensor, `r` means the up-scaling factor, `color` determine whether the channel of images is 3(Ycbcr format) or 1(Grayscale format).

To use the layer is very simple, just like the `tf.nn.relu()` does:

```
L3_ps = PS(L3, scale, True)
```

Now I'm wondering whether this layer caused the slowing-down, because the program goes well when using deconvolution layer. Using deconvolution layer may be a solution, but I have to use PS layer for some reason.

Comment: Can you time just the sess.run call? That's the only part which uses the tf runtime, and there could be slowness somewhere else. The way you use tf doesn't seem to trigger any graph growth during the loop (which does lead to slowness).

Comment: I've tried your suggestion: timing every `[_, cost1] = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {IN: LR_batch, OUT: HR_batch})`. I saw the slowing down every epoch. I'm wondering whether the PS layer caused the slowing-down, which has been added after the question description. @AlexandrePassos

Comment: I'm now observing this exact problem. Did you ever resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this line is causing a memory leak (although without seeing the code, I can't say for certain):

```
L3_test = model_test(IN_TEST, var_w_list, var_b_list, FLAGS)
```

`L3_test` seems to be a `tf.Tensor` (because you later pass it to `sess.run()`, so it seems likely that `model_test()` is adding new nodes to the graph each time it is called (every 1000 steps), which causes more work to be done over time.

The solution is quite simple though: since `model_test()` does not depend on anything calculated in the training loop, you can move the call to outside the training loop, so it is only called once.

Comment: Well, it is an important factor, I moved the `model_test()` outside the loop, and the network run a little faster. But it seemed not the vital factor as the time is still increasing every 100 epochs. I'm wondering whether the `PS` layer caused the slowing-down, which has been added after the question description.